# Is there any system views which show current and history plan information about SQL of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Sometims I want to monitor the performace of PostgreSQL DATABASE, I double  that the plan of  some sql statements were changed in the past. Is there any views which show current and history plan information about SQL of PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think your best bet is to log them with auto explain: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/11/23/waiting-for-84-auto-explain/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`auto_explain`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auto-explain.html) extension.  It can write the plans of all queries to the server log.

Answer (score 0):

Plan information is dynamic based on the current state of the DB, what the latest ANALYZE shows, statistics, etc.  These stats are accessible in the pg_stats view (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/planner-stats.html) which you could back up for later analysis.

Comment: Does PG prividers a view that show the history plan informaiton of q sql statements ?